# JSON request for envelope with single document, two signers, pre-fill fields

Tags: docusignapi

I have an envelope with a single document and two signers saved as a server-side template.  The signers execute the agreement in a specific order.  The document has a number of pre-fill fields in it.

I am trying to automate sending this agreement out using Integromat.  Unfortunately, Integromat's module doesn't allow for pre-fill fields in templates, leaving me to create the API request manually.  This is where I get stuck.

The closest I have come is the JSON request below, POSTed to:
*…/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes*, with capitalised values filled in automatically:

```
{
  "templateId": "TEMPLATE_ID",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "email": "CLIENT_EMAIL",
      "name": "CLIENT_NAME",
      "roleName": "Recipient",
      "tabs": {
        "prefillTabs": {
          "textTabs": [{
            "tabLabel": "Prefill: Purpose",
            "value": "PURPOSE_FIELD_DATA"
          }]
        }
      }
    }, {
      "email": "STAFF_EMAIL",
      "name": "STAFF_NAME",
      "roleName": "Company"
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent"
}
```

The response from the API is:

> The operation failed with an error. [400] A Required field is
> incomplete. TabId: GUI_HERE

What I can't figure out is how to get the pre-fill data submitted since it's not tied to a particular signer.  I have scoured the v2.1 API documentation but there is no scenario simple enough for this request.

Apologies if I am missing something obvious here; this is my first rodeo with DocuSign's API.

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong or, better yet, what the body of the request should be for this (presumably) simple scenario?

Comment: Welcome! ***Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** For pre-fill tabs, you need to have both the `tabId` and `tabLabel`, not enough to just have `tabLabel` like regular tabs.

My guess is a mismatch of the `tabId` field for the tabs on your template vs. what's in the API request:
You had this value in your request:

```
Prefill: Purpose
```

Does it match how the template was set?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Yes, it's an exact match for the "Data Label" attribute of this field in the DocuSign web UI.

Comment: Are there any other fields for which you didn't specify a value?

Comment: I only specify values for the pre-fill field(s) in each template.  I want the rest of them to filled in by the signers, just as if I'm sending the template out through the web UI.

Comment: You don't need to use the feature called "pre-fill" fields to prefill fields. You can use regular fields.

Comment: The one thing I like about it: sometimes, we still the template from the web UI, which means being prompted to pre-fill the fields before sending manually is helpful.

Comment: Are you saying you can do this (what you're trying to do) from the web UI and it works ok? if so - you should enable API logs to see what APIs are being called. The web UI uses the same API!

Comment: That helped me to find the solution.  Short answer: simply specifying the tabLabel isn’t enough; the API needs the tabId in order to set the value.  If anyone else needs help getting this to work (particularly with Integromat), message me privately.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this with composite templates.
When I added the prefill tabs to a recipient I received the error

```
Error code: INVALID_TAB_OPERATION.

Message: The Tab specified is not valid for the requested operation. 
PrefillTab not allowed for recipient.
```

which makes sense since prefill tabs are associated with a document, not a recipient.

I tried by adding a document to the composite template, but that didn't work either.

I suggest that you use regular tabs. Mark them `locked` so they can't be changed. Mark them `shared` so every signer will see them. Then fill in their values as part of your Envelopes:create call.

Here's a [live example](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Set%20template%20tabs) of doing this. Note the `text2` tab which is locked. (It should have the `shared` attribute set to true. You can add that from the Tabs/text toolbox on the left.)

Also see this [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/use-template-luke) about templates.

Comment: Larry, thanks for the information.  Does this mean there is no way to pre-fill fields in templates via the API?

Comment: Answer: not that I know of. To pursue further, please open a case with DocuSign's developer support team.

Answer (score 0):

Integromat does even without using DocuSign Rest APIs.
You can use Powerforms, it will save your cost for Rest APIs.

I recently did this, but issue is for first recipient, you need to send email manually with powerform link.

Here I dynamically construct PowerForm URL where I pass values to pre populate template fields.

To send email from integromat, you can configure Gmail module or any other email module and create html template where you can append Powerform URL in anchor tag